# Retrieving Data from Firebase under ChildByAutoId and adding to array - Xcode - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Database from Firebase:

[image]

Im trying to get the data for all purchases and quantities under "Tgb9MyxTfdTRd9tQhInsjNRXoPL2" and add to an array.

Here is my code:

```
    func fetchPurchase(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Purchase) -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("purchases").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            print("dict-->", dict)
        let purchase = Purchase(uid: uid, dictionary: dict)
            print("purchase-->", purchase)
        completion(purchase)
    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch purchase from database:", err)
    }
}
```

This is the print out for `print("dict-->", dict)`:

```
dict--> ["-LzjaFBgD3ATl7e8uR2-": {
purchase = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0Lzk4OTUzMjEyODM=";
quantity = 1;
}, "-LzjaFBiAmrj4m3ZS8m4": {
purchase = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0Lzk4OTUzMDk2OTk=";
quantity = 2;
}]
```

This is the print out for `print("purchase-->", purchase)`:

```
 purchase--> Purchase(uid: "Tgb9MyxTfdTRd9tQhInsjNRXoPL2", purchases: "", quantities: "")
```

The value dict holds the data I need, but I cant get past that to put the data into an array to display it?

How can I get the purchase and quantity data into their own arrays?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```
    func fetchPurchase(withUID uid: String, completion: @escaping (Purchase) -> ()) {
            Database.database().reference().child("purchases").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                self.YourArrayList.removeAll()
                 for dict in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                    let purchase = Purchase(uid: uid, dictionary: dict)
                    self.YourArrayList.append(purchase)
                }

            }
            completion(purchase)
        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch purchase from database:", err)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the i inside the for loop?

Comment: Not a big issue but you've cast all of the snapshot child nodes to`[DataSnapshot]` (which is spot on) but your loop var is called `dict` which is a little misleading as it looks like the Purchase object is expecting a `Dictionary`, not a `DataSnapshot`. Probably should call it childSnap or snap for clarity or cast it to a dict `[String: Any]`. Other than that, great answer.